# Which nonterminal is the start symbol?

Tags: javascript, ecma262

While i was reading the spec([ECMAScript 2022](https://tc39.es/ecma262/)) i've wondered which nonterminal symbol is the start symbol ?
in other words the first place that is being evaluated in [ECMAScript 2022](https://tc39.es/ecma262/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*It depends.* The abstract operation [ParseText](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-parsetext) is called from 14 places, with different *goalSymbols* (from the perspective of a bottom-up parser the start symbol of the generative grammar is the goal). The call you are probably looking for comes from *ParseScript* and passes in the *Script* non-terminal symbol (though it might also be *Module* passed in from *ParseModule*).